Golang Memory Leak: pprof Unable to Locate the Source
Differences among Golang runtime, pprof, and the ps aux command
I found that the results of monitoring Go memory with ps aux, pprof, and the Go runtime package are completely different. Only the Go runtime package has achieved correct monitoring, while pprof observed much less memory.
The following is a small coding experiment.
The following code should theoretically result in a 200MB memory leak
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"  
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil)
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            var m runtime.MemStats
            runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
            fmt.Printf("Alloc = %v MiB", bToMb(m.Alloc))
            fmt.Printf("\tTotalAlloc = %v MiB", bToMb(m.TotalAlloc))
            fmt.Printf("\tSys = %v MiB", bToMb(m.Sys))
            fmt.Printf("\tNumGC = %v\n", m.NumGC)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }

    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("start test")
    var memoryLeaks [][]int32
    t := 0
    for {
        leak := make([]int32, 5*1024*1024) // allocat 5*4=20mb
        memoryLeaks = append(memoryLeaks, leak)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // Slightly delay to observe changes in memory usage
        t += 1
        if t == 10 {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("end test")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Hour)
    fmt.Println("test", memoryLeaks[1][333]) // avoid being collected by gc 

}

func bToMb(b uint64) uint64 {
    return b / 1024 / 1024
}

golang print result:
Alloc = 0 MiB   TotalAlloc = 0 MiB      Sys = 7 MiB     NumGC = 0
Alloc = 0 MiB   TotalAlloc = 0 MiB      Sys = 7 MiB     NumGC = 0
Alloc = 0 MiB   TotalAlloc = 0 MiB      Sys = 7 MiB     NumGC = 0
Alloc = 0 MiB   TotalAlloc = 0 MiB      Sys = 7 MiB     NumGC = 0
Alloc = 0 MiB   TotalAlloc = 0 MiB      Sys = 7 MiB     NumGC = 0
start test
Alloc = 20 MiB  TotalAlloc = 20 MiB     Sys = 29 MiB    NumGC = 1
Alloc = 20 MiB  TotalAlloc = 20 MiB     Sys = 29 MiB    NumGC = 1
Alloc = 40 MiB  TotalAlloc = 40 MiB     Sys = 49 MiB    NumGC = 2
Alloc = 40 MiB  TotalAlloc = 40 MiB     Sys = 49 MiB    NumGC = 2
Alloc = 60 MiB  TotalAlloc = 60 MiB     Sys = 69 MiB    NumGC = 2
Alloc = 60 MiB  TotalAlloc = 60 MiB     Sys = 69 MiB    NumGC = 2
Alloc = 80 MiB  TotalAlloc = 80 MiB     Sys = 90 MiB    NumGC = 3
Alloc = 80 MiB  TotalAlloc = 80 MiB     Sys = 90 MiB    NumGC = 3
Alloc = 100 MiB TotalAlloc = 100 MiB    Sys = 110 MiB   NumGC = 3
Alloc = 100 MiB TotalAlloc = 100 MiB    Sys = 110 MiB   NumGC = 3
Alloc = 120 MiB TotalAlloc = 120 MiB    Sys = 130 MiB   NumGC = 3
Alloc = 120 MiB TotalAlloc = 120 MiB    Sys = 130 MiB   NumGC = 3
Alloc = 140 MiB TotalAlloc = 140 MiB    Sys = 151 MiB   NumGC = 3
Alloc = 140 MiB TotalAlloc = 140 MiB    Sys = 151 MiB   NumGC = 3
Alloc = 160 MiB TotalAlloc = 160 MiB    Sys = 171 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 160 MiB TotalAlloc = 160 MiB    Sys = 171 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 180 MiB TotalAlloc = 180 MiB    Sys = 191 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 180 MiB TotalAlloc = 180 MiB    Sys = 191 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
end test
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4
Alloc = 200 MiB TotalAlloc = 200 MiB    Sys = 212 MiB   NumGC = 4

use "ps aux | grep pid" result:
2024-04-10 19:26:43 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408693376  10480
2024-04-10 19:26:44 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:45 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:46 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:47 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:48 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:49 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:50 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:51 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:52 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:53 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:54 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:56 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:57 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:58 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:26:59 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:00 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:01 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:02 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:03 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:04 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:05 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:06 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:07 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:08 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:09 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:10 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:11 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:12 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:13 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:14 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:15 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:16 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:17 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:18 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:19 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:20 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:21 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:22 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:23 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:24 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:25 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:26 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:27 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:28 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:30 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:31 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376
2024-04-10 19:27:32 %MEM      VSZ    RSS 0.1 408730080  21376

pprof diff result：(Take h1 before the start of testing as the benchmark, and h2 after the end of testing as the analysis file）
pprof diff result
I created a program with a 200MB memory leak. Why does the Go runtime package correctly show the 200MB leak, but monitoring the process with the ps aux command shows almost no growth, and monitoring with pprof shows only an 80MB increase?
I want "ps aux" commond and pprof and golang runtime package give same result but not.

You can access the values, so there is no leak. The OS shows little difference in used memory, because you have not really used any of that memory.
